# Sharepoint Aging Column

Tags: sharepoint

I will keep it simple - I have a list that will include 'creation date' as a required field. I need the next column to display the dynamic aging (essentially taking today's date and subtracting 'creation date').

Is this possible in Sharepoint Office 365? And if so what's the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Calculated Column and use the formula

```
=TODAY()-[CreationDate]
```

That will return the number of days between Today and your 'creation date' column

Useful link:

- [Calculated Filed Formulas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)) - it says it is applicable to SharePoint 2010 but some could work in O365